# Javascript - iterate to the next element based on condition

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop

I'm stuck on how to iterate to the next element based on the condition in a function. Once the user highlights the right word and the message well done gets displayed, it should move on to the next definition/word taken from the array onA. At the bottom, I've put a pseudo code, as I don't know how to access the result of the conditional statement from the function.

```
var onA = [
    {t: "grooming", d: "an activity when someone builds an emotional connection with a child to gain their trust for the purposes of sexual abuse or exploitation."},
    {t: "cyberbullying", d: "an activity that involves the use of ICT, particularly mobile phones and the internet, deliberately to upset, threaten and intimidate someone else."}
];


function getSelectionHandler(index) {
    return function clickHandler() {

    var txt = '';
    var feedback = document.querySelector("#onA .feedback");

    if (window.getSelection) {
        txt = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

    // Display the selected text
    document.querySelector("#onA .word").innerHTML = txt;

    // Change the type of bootstrap alert depending on success
    function feed(oldClass, newClass, message) {
        feedback.classList.remove(oldClass);
        feedback.classList.add(newClass);
        feedback.innerHTML = message.bold();
    }

    // Check if the selected word is correct
    if (txt === onA[index].t) {
        feed("alert-warning", "alert-success", "Well done!");
    } else {
        feed("alert-success", "alert-warning", "Try again!");
    }
    };
}


var i = 0

while (i<onA.length) {
    document.getElementById("onA").onclick = getSelectionHandler(i);
    document.querySelector("#onA .def").innerHTML += onA[i].d;
    if condition in the if statement above is true:
       i++
}
```

Comment: Do you want only clicking 'cyberbullying' being successful only after clicking 'grooming' being successful? Or it does not matter, two clicking are independent?

Comment: First, the definition of 'grooming' is displayed and the user needs to click on 'grooming'. After that, the second item of the array will be shown, ie. the definition of cyberbullying and then they will have to click on 'cyberbullying'.

Answer (score 0):

Global variable can be used to record the current state. I just write it bear hand, you have to debug it if necessary.

```
function getSelectionHandler(){
    var txt = '';
    var feedback = document.querySelector("#onA .feedback");

    if (window.getSelection) {
        txt = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

    // Display the selected text
    document.querySelector("#onA .word").innerHTML = txt;

    // Change the type of bootstrap alert depending on success
    function feed(oldClass, newClass, message) {
        feedback.classList.remove(oldClass);
        feedback.classList.add(newClass);
        feedback.innerHTML = message.bold();
    }

    // Check if the selected word is correct
    if (txt === onA[index].t) {
        feed("alert-warning", "alert-success", "Well done!");
        index++;    //increase before showing next or checking end
        if (checkEnded()){
            //all end, show end msg
            feed("alert-warning", "alert-success", "Finish!");
        }else {
            //show next
            showNext();
        }
    } else {
        feed("alert-success", "alert-warning", "Try again!");
    }
}

function checkEnded(){
    return index >= onA.length;
}

function showNext(){
    document.querySelector("#onA .def").innerHTML += onA[index].d;  //display next item

}

var index = 0;  //global index for selecting from the array
document.getElementById("onA").onclick = function(){getSelectionHandler();} //register hanlder onc time only
document.querySelector("#onA .def").innerHTML += onA[index].d;      //display first item
```

Comment: Thanks but the highlighting mechanism and feedback function has stopped working. Worse still, it does not throw any error in the console. Have been trying to find out why.

Comment: Ok. Got it working. Just needed to remove the () from the last but one line. Now the only thing remains is to put something before index++ to confirm that the user wants to move on to the next question.

Comment: glad to see you get it working. I just look into http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp. It seems the statement for the onclick handle should be `document.getElementById("onA").onclick = function(){getSelectionHandler();}`